# Generate all posible combinations of elements in 3 lists of strings?

Tags: python, string, combinations, permutation

I need to generate ALL possible combinations of EACH element in each list of strings

```
list1 = ['The girl', 'The boy']
list2 = ['wears', 'touches', 'tries']
list3 = ['a red sweater', 'a blue sweater', 'a yellow sweater', 'a white sweater']
```

So the result is a list of a string combining each element combines with each other element:

```
The girl wears a red sweater
The boy wears a red sweater
The girl touches a red sweater
The boy touches a red sweater
The girl wears a blue sweater
The boy wears a yellow sweater
(ETC...)
```

I don't particularly care about the order of the output as long as ALL combinations are obtained.

From my research I guess "permutation" would be a solution but I only found several answers regarding permutations of lists of *numbers*, or combinations of each letter in a string. None of those things is what I need. *I need to combine blocks of text arranged in lists.*

How can I create a long list of sentences containing all of the combinations of the different elements in each one of the lists of strings?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using itertools' product, its as simple as :

```
import itertools
["{x} {y} {z}".format(x=x,y=y,z=z) for x,y,z in itertools.product(list1, list2, list3)]
```

And in python 3.6, you can drop the `format` call

```
[f"{x} {y} {z}" for x,y,z in itertools.product(list1, list2, list3)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just a bunch of simple for loops will works. The trick is the order of print `z,y,x`.

```
list1 = ['The girl', 'The boy']
list2 = ['wears', 'touches', 'tries']
list3 = ['a red sweater', 'a blue sweater', 'a yellow sweater', 'a white sweater']

for x in list3:
    for y in list2:
        for z in list1:
            print (z,y,x)
```

Output;

```
The girl wears a red sweater
The boy wears a red sweater
The girl touches a red sweater
The boy touches a red sweater
The girl tries a red sweater
The boy tries a red sweater
The girl wears a blue sweater
The boy wears a blue sweater
The girl touches a blue sweater
The boy touches a blue sweater
The girl tries a blue sweater
The boy tries a blue sweater
The girl wears a yellow sweater
The boy wears a yellow sweater
The girl touches a yellow sweater
The boy touches a yellow sweater
The girl tries a yellow sweater
The boy tries a yellow sweater
The girl wears a white sweater
The boy wears a white sweater
The girl touches a white sweater
The boy touches a white sweater
The girl tries a white sweater
The boy tries a white sweater
```

Comment: I tried this but got confused on the way. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product), the handy tool for a cartesian product. Then [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) the products:

```
from itertools import product
lst = [' '.join(p) for p in product(list1, list2, list3)]

from pprint import pprint
pprint(lst)
['The girl wears a red sweater',
 'The girl wears a blue sweater',
 'The girl wears a yellow sweater',
 'The girl wears a white sweater',
 'The girl touches a red sweater',
 'The girl touches a blue sweater',
 'The girl touches a yellow sweater',
 'The girl touches a white sweater',
 'The girl tries a red sweater',
 'The girl tries a blue sweater',
 'The girl tries a yellow sweater',
 'The girl tries a white sweater',
 'The boy wears a red sweater',
 'The boy wears a blue sweater',
 'The boy wears a yellow sweater',
 'The boy wears a white sweater',
 'The boy touches a red sweater',
 'The boy touches a blue sweater',
 'The boy touches a yellow sweater',
 'The boy touches a white sweater',
 'The boy tries a red sweater',
 'The boy tries a blue sweater',
 'The boy tries a yellow sweater',
 'The boy tries a white sweater']
```